# Is it OK to name a variable with the same name as a structure tag?

Tags: c

Is it OK to name a variable with the same name as a structure tag?  For example:

```
struct sth {
  char *a;
  int b;
};

struct asdf {
  struct sth sth; // is second sth OK??
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is productive? What advantage do you think you will have?

Comment: Yap. `struct` uses it's own namespace, different from other type, variable or function names. That is why the compiler complains when you try to use a struct without the `struct` keyword.

Comment: You can do, but what is advantage you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Is your question "Will it reliably compile?" then the answer is yes (see answers below). If your question is "Is it a good idea?" then the answer is no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Structure tags are in the 'tag' name space, shared with unions and enumerations.  This is wholly separate from the 'ordinary identifier' name space (holding typedef names and variable names and function names), and also from the per-structure member names namespace.

That means you could have:

```
struct sth       // DO
{                // NOT
    int sth;     // DO
} sth;           // THIS!
```

This declares a structure variable `sth` of type `struct sth` with one member named `sth`.

The compiler can keep all that straight; you probably can't and probably shouldn't.  In other words, although you can write code like that, it would be an incredibly bad idea to actually do so.

Comment: So you can't have a variable name with the same name as the type def name?

Comment: @user129393192: If you define the type outside a function using something like `typedef struct sth { int sth; } sth;` then you could (but shouldn't) do: `extern sth something(int n);` — `sth something(int n) { sth sth = { n }; return sth; }` and it will compile cleanly (as long as you don't have the equivalent of GCC's `-Wshadow` option in your compiler command line.  But you couldn't create a second variable `sth sth2 = { n + 1 };` inside the function — you'd have to write `struct sth sth2 = { n + 1 };`.  But the whole setup is extremely dubious — ***don't do it!***

Comment: Sounds good. I went with `struct whatever_struct {} whatever;`. Interesting how the function namespace has to come first over the regular identifier inside the function to enable recursion.