# In C can a field of a struct and a variable have the same name?

Tags: c, struct, overloading

In C, can a field of a struct and a variable have the same name? Are there gonna be any issues? For example:

```
struct foo {
    int x
}

main() {
    struct foo j;
    int x = 666;
    j.x = x;
}
```

Is this valid?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276270/in-what-scope-is-a-struct-member-identifier-put

Comment: See [Is it OK to name a variable with the same name as a structure tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313593/) for a recent incarnation of this question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; OP is asking for a variable name same as the name of a struct member.

Comment: @haccks: and the answer to that question covers name spaces and includes members in a separate name space from both structure tags and ordinary identifiers.  So, the answer covers what this question needs as an answer.  I've not made it into a duplicate, though, please note.

Comment: In my opinion you should avoid it. When your code increases in size it becomes easy to get lost and do stupid errors because of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C, can a field of a struct and a variable have the same name?

Yes. That's because `struct`s have their own namespace. [C11 §6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)

> [...] Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the `.` or `->`operator);
>   — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Answer (score 0):

Yes because struct have another namespace and variable in main method have different namespace, you always access the struct variable by using reference of that like j.x.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct foo {
    int x;
};

void main() {
    struct foo j;
    int x = 666;
    j.x = x;
    printf("struct var x = %d\n",j.x);//struct var x = 666
}
```